# How to get multidimensional array from FORM via post, ajax, php, jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Please help me to reapair the code. I need array like this from ajax: car1['color of car']['story about car'].
But I can get only: car1['story about car'].
I have read a lot of tips, but without success. I am begginer at php.
Thanks a lot for concrete answer :)

```
// HTML smaller version
<form class= "ajax2" action="formInsertCar.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Save All">
    <div>
        <select name="car1[]" size="1">
            <?php $opt = new CarOptions;?>
        </select>
        <textarea name="car1[]"></textarea>
     </div>
    <div>
        <select name="car2[]" size="1">
            <?php $opt = new CarOptions;?>
        </select>
        <textarea name="car2[]"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>

// JavaScript, ajax for FORM
$('form.ajax2').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();

        data[name] = value;
        // here I want to result like: car1['color of car']['story about car'];
        // but I can get only: car1['story about car']
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('.success').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you will get an unwanted format by doing that.
I'd do it like:

```
<div>
    <select name="car[1][color]" size="1">
        <?php $opt = new CarOptions;?>
    </select>
    <textarea name="car[1][history]"></textarea>
 </div>
<div>
    <select name="car[2][color]" size="1">
        <?php $opt = new CarOptions;?>
    </select>
    <textarea name="car[2][history]"></textarea>
</div>
```

I would also change some of your javascript form submit listener:

```
$('form.ajax2').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //'return false' is deprecated according to jQuery documentation, use this instead.

    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = that.serialize(); //This will capture all form input values, no need to reinvent the wheel

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('.success').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

In the server side (PHP):

```
print_r($_POST)

/**
Will print the following data:

array() {
    car => array () {
        1 => array() {
            color => colorValue,
            history => historyValue
        },
        2 => array() {
            color => colorValue,
            history => historyValue
        }
    }
}
*/
```

Comment: Thanks you very much also  :) :) :). It works without changing html too :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below script ..........Use **Jquery FormData Class**

```
$('form.ajax2').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method');

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('.success').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```